# Replace list brackets in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple list objects

Example:

```
data = [['id', 'host'], [1, '123']]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['id', 'host'], [1, '123']]
```

When:

```
print(*data)
```

Output:

```
['id', 'host'] [1, '123']
```

When:

```
print(*data, sep='\n')
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, data)))
```

Output:

```
['id', 'host']
[1, '123']
```

How to make an output like this without brackets and commas:

```
id host
1  123
```

Comment: Write a for-loop.

Comment: Your desired output has some padding so that each column of data is aligned. Is that something you actually need? Because it makes it a *lot* more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward for loop gives your desired output:

```
data = [['id', 'host'], [1, '123']]
for d in data:
    print(*d)
```

If there's a problem with that approach, it's not apparent in your question.

If you're trying to produce a `str` result you can use a pair of `join` calls to convert the inner elements to `str` then join with spaces, then join those lines with `'\n'`

```
data = [['id', 'host'], [1, '123']]
result = '\n'.join(' '.join(str(e) for e in d) for d in data)
```

Comment: Thank you. The second one works for me 'print('\n'.join(', '.join(str(e) for e in d) for d in data))'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *for-loop* and the `str.join()` method to do this.

```
for sublist in data:
    print(" ".join(sublist))
```

This only works if you are working exclusively with string type data though, for your purposes, try this:

```
for sublist in data:
    print(" ".join([str(element) for element in sublist]))
```

Comment: This code gives an error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found". The original data has an int in it.

Comment: @VoidTwo Corrected it, please remove the downvote.

Comment: I will note that the double for-loop in the second solution is not advised with large data sets since the time complexity could be quite high.

Comment: @VoidTwo Well you have to iterate over the sublists somehow, what would be your suggestion? Your answer doesn't solve anything but the exact situation the OP asked about.

Comment: `print(*sublist)` would be a much simpler way to get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
print(*(f"{i:<4} {d}" for i,d in data),sep="\n")

id   host
1    123
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. Thanks to Ryan Haining.

```
print('\n'.join(', '.join(str(e) for e in d) for d in data))
```

I've added ', ' before join because I needed to record the output to csv format. Without this commas it will not format my output in the csv table

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to do it all in one line, you could use list comprehension with something like this:

```py
print('\n'.join([' '.join((str(itr[0]), str(itr[1]))) for itr in data]))
```

Another one-liner:

```py
print(*[' '.join((str(itr[0]), str(itr[1]))) for itr in data], sep='\n')
```

Comment: For those who have indicated that this answer is not useful, could you please explain how I could improve this answer? I have run this code myself with the given input and it prints the result the original questioner appears to be looking for.

Comment: I downvoted because I think it is a lot uglier and more complicated than just simply `for line in data: print(*line)`

Comment: You got downvotes because both of your solutions involve a lot more complexity than need be. For example, your second example would be similar to doing `print(*[x])` rather than `print(x)`